# Wordpress custom template on every new page (Elementor)

Tags: wordpress, templates, elementor

I have wordpress and am using Elementor editor. I have added a page that is meant to be a template for each new pages. I added  a block with breadcrumbs to this page. I want this page with breadcrumbs on evey new page that i create. Copying this page all the time creates problems, e.g. if I wanted to change something in this block so I must do this on every subpage. I do not know how to do it - all i want its one static page with that breadcrumbs that includes to every new page i create, and when im change something in this page, changes will appear on every page.

Help :( Photo below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1EyI.png

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Template" block in Elementor

Answer (score 0):

That is achievable with Elementor Pro using theme builder option.

Create that template as a single page template and then in display options choose to display it on all pages.

[Creating a Single Page Template with Elementor Pro](https://elementor.com/help/creating-a-single-page-template-with-elementor-pro/)

Then you should use standard page editor or custom fields to put content that is then going to be rendered by the template.

Doing that will let you make changes on all pages at once by editing the template.